# Custom Admin Login Fatal Error

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have this line of codes for my magento custom merchant panel for my magento project.

```
<?php
$store_id = 1;
require_once "../app/Mage.php";
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$username = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('username');
$password = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('password');
$session->login($username,$password);
$user = $session->getUser();    
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl()."merchant/validate-voucher.php";
if($session->isLoggedIn()==1){
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse(); 
}
```

I need help in fixing the memory leak issue on this code.

```
HP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291, referer: http://dev.supremedeals.com/merchant/
```

I am getting this error after i login and disappears when i hit enter again on my browser url bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**First Way:**

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app();    
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));   

$username = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('username');
$password = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('password');

$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername($username); // Here admin is the Username
if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
  Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
}

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
$session->setUser($user);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
$redirectUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)."merchant/validate-voucher.php";
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {

    header('Location: ' . $redirectUrl);
    exit;
}
?>
```

**Second Way:**

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php'; 
Mage::app();    
umask(0);

$store_id = 1;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));   

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$username = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('username');
$password = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('password');
$session->login($username,$password);
$user = $session->getUser();    
$redirectUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)."merchant/validate-voucher.php";
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    header('Location: ' . $redirectUrl);
    exit;
}
?>
```